# Leetcode: Maximal rectangle

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the [maximal rectangle problem](http://leetcode.com/onlinejudge#question_85) from LeetCode.

My implementation is separated into two phases.
The first phase construct a table `tabrec`.
for any i and j in the range of input matrix
`tabrec[i][j]` is undefined if `matrix[i][j] == '0'`, otherwise it records the maximum extension of the `'1'` in four directions (left, right, top, bottom).
In phase two, I compute the maximum rectangle by iterating through rows and columns.
For each row, I can identify the consecutive 1's in the same row.
Also I can find the minimum rectangle enclosing the row of 1's with the table built previously.

Here is the code

```
class Solution {
    struct Rect {
        int l;
        int r;
        int t;
        int b;
    };

public:
    int maximalRectangle(vector<vector<char> > &matrix) {
        // Start typing your C/C++ solution below
        // DO NOT write int main() function
        int row = matrix.size();
        int col = 0;
        if (row) col = matrix[0].size();

        if (!(row && col)) return 0;

        Rect *storage = new Rect[row * col];
        Rect **rectab = new Rect*[row];

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            rectab[i] = storage + i * col;

        // find the left most 1-extension for each point
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][0] == '1') rectab[i][0].l = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < col; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == '1') {
                    if (matrix[i][j - 1] == '1')
                        rectab[i][j].l = rectab[i][j - 1].l;
                    else
                        rectab[i][j].l = j;
                }
            }
        }
        // find the right most 1-extension for each point
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][col - 1] == '1') rectab[i][col - 1].r = col - 1;
            for (int j = col - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == '1') {
                    if (matrix[i][j + 1] == '1') rectab[i][j].r = rectab[i][j + 1].r;
                    else rectab[i][j].r = j;
                }
            }
        }
        // find the top most 1-extension for each point
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (matrix[0][j] == '1') rectab[0][j].t = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < row; i++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == '1') {
                    if (matrix[i - 1][j] == '1') rectab[i][j].t = rectab[i - 1][j].t;
                    else rectab[i][j].t = i;
                }
            }
        }
        // find the bottom most 1-extension for each point
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (matrix[row - 1][j] == '1') rectab[row - 1][j].b = row - 1;
            for (int i = row - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == '1') {
                    if (matrix[i + 1][j] == '1') rectab[i][j].b = rectab[i + 1][j].b;
                    else rectab[i][j].b = i;
                }
            }
        }

        int max = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < row) {
            while (j < col && matrix[i][j] == '0') j++;
            if (j < col) {
                int el = rectab[i][j].l;
                int er = rectab[i][j].r;
                int et = rectab[i][j].t;
                int eb = rectab[i][j].b;
                j++;
                while (j < col && matrix[i][j] == '1') {
                    Rect *rect = &rectab[i][j];
                    if (el < rect->l) el = rect->l;
                    if (er > rect->r) er = rect->r;
                    if (et < rect->t) et = rect->t;
                    if (eb > rect->b) eb = rect->b;

                    j++;
                }

                if (max < (er - el + 1) * (eb - et + 1))
                    max = (er - el + 1) * (eb - et + 1);

                if (j == col) {
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                }
            } else {
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }

        delete [] storage;
        delete [] rectab;

        return max;
    }
};
```

This implementation can pass the small data set test, while fail 4 cases in large dataset.

I can't figure out the problem.
Anything wrong with my algorithm (I think it's right) or some bugs in my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your algorithm:

```
        while (j < col && matrix[i][j] == '1') {
            Rect *rect = &rectab[i][j];
            if (el < rect->l) el = rect->l;
            if (er > rect->r) er = rect->r;
            if (et < rect->t) et = rect->t;
            if (eb > rect->b) eb = rect->b;

            j++;
        }

        if (max < (er - el + 1) * (eb - et + 1))
            max = (er - el + 1) * (eb - et + 1);
```

Here, you should put if sentence inside the while loop. Because sometimes, you don't need to reach the final 1 of the current line. See an example:

```
0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

The answer should be 6, but your algorithm will return 4 instead.

Even with the above change, it is still not correct. Actually, this problem is better to solve using DP. Search largest 2d array sum for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Search largest 2d array for reference", could you please elaborate it? A naive maximum sum policy will of course not work, e.g. in you example, the sum of total region is no less than any sub-2d-array. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea You can use a small trick based on naive maximum sum algorithm: if matrix[i][j]==0, set it to -MAX_INT, if matrix[i][j]==1, don't change. Then you can apply maximum sum algorithm directly.